# TFS Build Delete all files matching pattern before publishing

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to delete all files in any directory matching a set of patterns in my build output directory before publishing and it's not finding anything that matches the pattern I have defined.  The pattern I'm using is:

`**\?(*.cfg|*.config|*.xml)\**`

I enabled system.debug in my build and I can see the following file being seen in the source directory I specified:

`2018-03-12T00:43:31.5264940Z ##[debug]  C:\agent3\_work\3\nsis_workspace\AutoBagPack.log4net.config
2018-03-12T00:43:31.5264940Z ##[debug]    is a file`

The above file should match the `*.config` portion of my minimatch pattern but at the end of the log for this task I see:

`2018-03-12T00:43:32.4327498Z ##[debug]2454 results
2018-03-12T00:43:32.4327498Z ##[debug]match patterns: C:\agent3\_work\3\nsis_workspace\**\?(*.cfg|*.config|*.xml)\**
2018-03-12T00:43:32.4327498Z ##[debug]match options: [object Object]
2018-03-12T00:43:32.4327498Z ##[debug]applying pattern: C:\agent3\_work\3\nsis_workspace\**\?(*.cfg|*.config|*.xml)\**
2018-03-12T00:43:32.5108753Z ##[debug]matched 0 items`

My source path is defined as and can be seen in the log as:

`2018-03-12T00:43:31.4952438Z ##[debug]SourceFolder=C:\agent3\_work\3\nsis_workspace
2018-03-12T00:43:31.4952438Z ##[debug]BuildCleanup=null
2018-03-12T00:43:31.4952438Z ##[debug]patterns: C:\agent3\_work\3\nsis_workspace\**\?(*.cfg|*.config|*.xml)\**`

Why are all the *.cfg, *.config, *.xml files not being deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this code instead in Delete Files task (multiple lines):

```
**/*.cfg
**/*.xml
**/*.config
```

Or

```
**/?(*.xml|*.cfg|*.config)
```

Comment: I am using TFS 2018 , Delete files task, need to keep only 2 folders bin and reports, what would be the content pattern ?